# How to Change OpenSSL SSL/TLS Default Port [ 443 ] to new port?

Tags: c++, openssl

I have created a openssl certificate and installed it in Windows MMC Console

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -host Dev -port 443
```

The above command displays the certificate.

But i couldn't able change the port. I need to set custom port. [image]

Comment: You mean you want the SSL/TLS server to listen on port other than 443, where you will connect with s_client?

Comment: Yeah @Pras I need custom change the default port to something new . User defined . Is it possible !

Comment: That depends on the server, is it the application you wrote, or standard webserver like apache, or is it the openssl command with s_server?

Comment: I am currently doing it for windows so it might be s_server

Comment: s_server has -port option you can specify the port you want there, then in s_client in -connect you can specify the new port to connect to openssl(s_server) server